# Getting data from Access table using VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I know this is a beginners issue, but switching back and forth from VB.NET and VB6 gets me confused some times. I'm trying to retrieve email addresses from an Access table I've created and store them in a string for later use. Here's what I have so far;

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim MyConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim MyRecSet1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim EmailList As String
    Set MyConn = New ADODB.Connection

    EmailList = ""

    MyConn.ConnectionString = "Some String"

    MyConn.Open

    Set MyRecSet1 = MyConn.Execute("SELECT DISTRIBUTION_LIST.[EMAIL_ADDRESS] FROM DISTRIBUTION_LIST")

    EmailList = MyRecSet1!EMAIL_ADDRESS

    MyConn.Close

    lblHeadDesc.Caption = EmailList

End Sub
```

I'm able to get 1 email address, but I want to get them all.

Comment: Make `EmailList` a `Variant` instead of `String` and change `EmailList = MyRecSet1!EMAIL_ADDRESS` to `EmailList = MyRecSet.GetRows`

Comment: Then how do I convert the type Variant to type String to use later?

Comment: There's always the `CStr()` function, but I'm not sure what you're using them for. Did my suggestion work?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but I keep getting a type missmatch error. Once I get it converted to a String I can display it in a caption.

Comment: Dim MyConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim MyRecSet1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim VarList As Variant
    Dim EmailList As String
    Set MyConn = New ADODB.Connection

    Set MyRecSet1 = MyConn.Execute("SELECT DISTRIBUTION_LIST.[EMAIL_ADDRESS] FROM DISTRIBUTION_LIST")
    
    VarList = MyRecSet1.GetRows

    MyConn.Close
    
    EmailList = CStr(VarList)  <==== Type missmatch.
    
    lblHeadDesc.Caption = EmailList

Comment: Forget the `CStr` for the moment (I don't think that is the correct way to go about it anyway). Is `VarList` Null when your code runs?

Comment: When I debug it, I hover over VarList and it doesn't show anything.

Comment: See if [this](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_ado_load_array.html) helps.

Comment: I used;    For i = LBound(VarList, 1) To UBound(VarList, 1)
        EmailList = EmailList + VarList(i) & ";"
    Next i

Comment: And I get Subscript out of range.

Comment: It seems like `VarList` is still empty? Is this true?

Comment: I guess it is coming back empty. However there are two rows in the table. and before I started messing with the Variant type, I was able to get at least 1 of the row's data.

Comment: I added this     For i = LBound(VarList, 2) To UBound(VarList, 2)
        For j = LBound(VarList, 1) To UBound(VarList, 1)
            EmailList = EmailList + VarList(i, j) & "; "
        Next j
    Next i and it shows 1 email record and on the second pass it says Script out of range;

Comment: Ok, I just had the I and J switched. It needs to be VarList(j,i)

Comment: Good job. What was the problem with records not getting to VarList?

Answer (score 1):

When reading, you can get all rows by looping until the EOF is set:

```
Do While Not MyRecSet1.EOF
  EmailAddress = MyRecSet1!EMAIL_ADDRESS
  'Do something with EmailAddress
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misinterpreted your question, but it sounds like you want the Recordset's `GetString()` method:

```
With MyConn.Execute("SELECT EMAIL_ADDRESS FROM DISTRIBUTION_LIST", , adCmdText)
    EmailList = .GetString(adClipString, , , vbNewLine)
    .Close
End With
MsgBox EmailList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = LBound(VarList, 2) To UBound(VarList, 2)
    For j = LBound(VarList, 1) To UBound(VarList, 1)
        EmailList = EmailList + VarList(j, i) & ", "
    Next j
Next i
```

Gets all of the email addresses.

Thanks OverMind for your assistance.